# Parse Password Reset

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am new to parse, trying to reset a password by:

```
user.requestPasswordResetInBackground(password.getText().toString(), new RequestPasswordResetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password rest email has been sent to your inbox", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }else if(e.getCode()== com.parse.ParseException.INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Email not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Everything is fine an email will be sent to the inbox, by how I can tell Parse to validate the password at least 8 characters (it's taking everything even 1234)
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can write a `cloud code`, so before _User object is updated, check user.get("password").length. 
Something Like this:

```
PF.Cloud.beforeSave("_User", function(request, response) {
    //Prototype linking
    var user = request.object;
    if (user.get("password").length >= 8) {
        response.success();
    } else {
        response.error("Password too short");
    }
});
```

For more information, please visit the reference: [Cloud Code](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-beforesave-triggers)